# how to update UILabel using sockets

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, swift, mean-stack

I am trying to update a UILabel using swift and sockets. I have a Mean stack app working with sockets now. It updates a simple counter when a user presses a button. How could I use sockets and update a UILabel when a user presses a button on the client side of my Mean stack app? Below is the swift code I'm using to update the counter. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SocketsController: UIViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var socketLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func buttonOnePressed(sender: UIButton) {
    socket.emit("javascript")
}

@IBAction func buttonTwoPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    socket.emit("swift")

}


let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "192.168.15.92:8000")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    socket.connect()

    socket.on("connect") { data, ack in
        println("iOS::WE ARE USING SOCKETS!")

    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this great tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) from RayWenderlich.com

Jump to the iOS part since you already have a running server.
There is no direct answer to your question since socket programming needs a few more steps to give the results you want ;)